# If the expectation exists and finite, is it always integrable?

Tags: probability

If the expectation of a random variable exists and finite, i.e., $EX<\infty$, is it always true that $E |X|<\infty$?

This question arises when I try to prove some stochastic process is a martingale. In the definition of martingale, we need the process to be integrable. But if we already know its expectation and it's finite, do we still have to prove that $E|X|<\infty$? 
For example, $W_t^2-t/2$, where $W_t$ is a Wiener process. We know that $E(W_t^2-t/2)=t/2<\infty$, do we have to calculate $E|W_t^2-t/2|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, yes, $E|X|<\infty$. If $E|X| = \infty$, then either $E(X^+)$ or $E(X^-)$ is $\pm\infty$, and $EX$ can't be finite, since $EX = EX^+ + EX^-$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by definition.  $E(X)$ is only defined when $X$ is absolutely integrable with respect to the probability measure.